# Cyrillic tag may contain wrong link (Favorite tags editor)

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

When you press on tag in Favorite tags panel it should redirect you to it's page, e.g. https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B , but sometimes it contains such links as https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/D1C8CDCECDC8CCDB

Some of them contains wrong link only when that editor is open, other will stay that way some time after.

Examples:

- синонимы: https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/D1C8CDCECDC8CCDB
- математика: https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/CCC0D2C5CCC0D2C8CAC0

Comment: Thanks, I have a repro ([proof](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ugA51.png)) - on my list for tomorrow morning, along with repairing the tag-badges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should now be resolved (or in a few minutes when the deploy completes). This only affected the client-side rendering when adding tags on-the-fly via the favorite tags panel; once the page had been refreshed it was fine - but the client side code should now behave itself properly.